# Download attempt failed

Tags: downloads

I just purchased Ubuntu 32 bit today.  While downloading, my internet connection failed. How can I re-attempt the download Ubuntu Desktop without having to pay for it.

Comment: Sorry to say this but you most probally have benn duped. Ubuntu is open source and can be downloaded for free http://www.ubuntu.com/download

Comment: As highlighted in the top answer, the download procedure is pretty pushy about getting people to donate before downloading.  I don't think I'd class that as being duped but it is optional. If you *didn't* get it from ubuntu.com and paid for the download, that might be different.

Answer (score 5):

you can download it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)

you shouldn't have to pay for it. "Ubuntu is completely free to download, use and share." Donations are of course accepted. If you do not widh to donate, click this button at the bottom of the donate page:

[image]

Source: http://www.ubuntu.com/download